# Physics : pressure and height

Tags: height, physics, pressure

If the pressure of air inside a ballon is H, so what is the depth at which the balloon dive under water surface to make the volume of the air decreases to its third?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems unrelated to programming

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems unrelated to programming

Answer (score -1):

After some searching for formulas i come up with
`2H/9 806.65`
H must be expressed in SI units for this calculation to work i.e. pascals (newtons per square meter)